# Cant read files twice on native scanner

Tags: java, tomcat, native

Please find stack trace below

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'msQmsFlowDownOrgVDaoHome': Injection of
persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'ecpEntityManager' defined in URL
[jar:file:/C:/SYSTEMi/Systemi/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ms-bcm-ecp-intg.jar!/spring-config/ecp/applicationContext-ecp-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>:
file:/C:/SYSTEMi/Systemi/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ms-bcm-ecp-intg.jar
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:342)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'ecpEntityManager' defined in URL
[jar:file:/C:/SYSTEMi/Systemi/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ms-bcm-ecp-intg.jar!/spring-config/ecp/applicationContext-ecp-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>:
file:/C:/SYSTEMi/Systemi/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ms-bcm-ecp-intg.jar
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:99)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findNamedEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:511)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:493)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:630)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:339)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>:
file:/C:/SYSTEMi/Systemi/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ms-bcm-ecp-intg.jar
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:596)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:268)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Cannot read files twice on NativeScanner
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getFilesInJar(NativeScanner.java:166)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:503)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:851)
        ... 48 more
```

I  get this following error while starting the tomcat server(windows) or websphere server(linux).
Can any one help me out in this?

is this related to some jar incompatibility of JPA,spring and hibernate?

I use following versions of jar.

```
Spring -->3.1.1 hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar.
hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final.jar
```

if yes let me know the jar version.

It works well on tomcat server with linux os.

Answer (score 0):

probably a bug in hibernate.  Such as:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8286

try a newer version.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion.But still the same issue.